# How do I list onedrive folder in powershell?

Tags: powershell, onedrive

I have a onedrive folder mapped to my folder on my pc.

​Suppose I am at this path in powershell: "C:\Users\bob\OneDrive\MyContainer"

I type the following powershell command:

```
ls ​"C:\Users\bob\OneDrive\MyContainer"
```

The error message being returned is as follows:

```
Get-ChildItem: Cannot find drive. A drive with the name '​C' does not exist.
```

why does onedrive fail to work with powershell?

Comment: Is this the complete code you're using? Is this the complete error message you're getting?

Comment: I've had this happen before. Don't paste the string, try to use tab-completion to set it for you. Then run the command and see if it happens again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have an invisible character between ls and the first ".

Comment: You are right, there is an invisible character in between ls and the first ".  This is because of copying and pasting something.  I retyped the command manually and it works.  Thanks!